# VBA variables defined one sub and called in another in multiple subs

Tags: vba, excel

I want to call a sub that I've written in another sub, and add a couple new things to it, but use the variables that I've defined in the first sub don't show up in the second, even though the first macro is called within the sub.

For example, I've defined the variables as Public outside of the subs, but the values I define in the first sub, and then call in second sub gets lost.  In the code below, running the macro "test" works, but "test1" gives me a "Run-time error '1004'".

```
Public row1 As Integer
Public col1 As Integer

Sub test()

row1 = 2
col1 = 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(row1, col1).Select

End Sub

Sub test1()

Call test

ActiveSheet.Cells(row1, col1).Resize(6, 5).Select

End Sub
```

Any guidance on how to get row1 and col1 to work in the test1 sub would be great.  Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: code works for me as is. I would recommend qualify the sheet you want to work to a variable `Dim ws as Worksheet | Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")` and working with that ws.Cells(row1,col1).Resize(6,5).Select`, but since this is probably just test code for the question it's probably not that big of a deal.

Comment: Why do the subs have to be split?  If you are doing some complex thing in another sub, you can pass variables through the call and then back with a result.

Comment: Thanks, Scott Holtzman, but I don't understand -- doesn't the "ActiveSheet." take care of that?  Also, would you put the "Dim ws" statement in the first sub, or both?

Comment: Chrismas007: the first sub/macro is updating/refreshing data that I want to leave as dynamic while in a session, and the second sub is going to freeze those values so they can be used offline.  I want to call the updating macro before freezing the data to be sure everything is current, but the second sub will use many of the variables in the first sub.  Does that make sense?  I can re-assign the variables in the second sub, but it seems like the variables should already be a defined since it's calling the macro.  But may I'm misunderstanding how this works in VB.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option is to pass variables from sub to use a Public Function like this:

```
Sub MainSubHere()
    'Some random code
    Dim AddMe1 As Long, AddMe2 As Long, MySum As Long
    AddMe1 = 2
    AddMe2 = 2
    MySum = AddMeSub(AddMe1, AddMe2)
    Msgbox MySum
End Sub

Public Function AddMeSub(AddMe1 As Long, AddMe2 As Long) As Long
    AddMeSub = AddMe1 + AddMe2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, but there's other stuff to improve here, such as using `Select` rathering then just going to the action statement. I left out that sub out since it served no purpose.

```
Dim row1 As Integer, col1 As Integer

Private Sub DefineVars()
Set row1 = 2
Set col1 = 2

End Sub

Sub test()

Call DefineVars

ActiveSheet.Cells(row1, col1).Resize(6, 5).Select

End Sub
```